# Syntax for exporting multiple objects from a .js file while maintaining a "default export"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an existing `common.js` file that exports only one object from it. As a result, another existing `some_other_file_1.js` file includes the line `const common = require('common')` and is able to use that export.

I would like to modify `common.js` to export additional objects, without having to modify `some_other_file_1.js`. Those additional objects will be used by other files. What is the syntax for that?

---

My current code:

*some_other_file_1.js* (I must not modify this file)

```js
const common = require('common')

const foo = () => {
  common.dostuff()
}
```

*common.js* (the file I want to modify)

```js
const common = {
  dostuff: () => {
    // code I've omitted
  },
}

const cool_func = () => {
  // code I've omitted
}

module.exports = common
// >>> I wish to also export cool_func <<<
```

Comment: What have you tried? What was the issue with it?

Comment: If you don't edit `some_other_file_1.js` how do you want to run `cool_func` inside of it?

Comment: @Konrad They probably want to import `cool_func` in another file, not `some_other_file_1.js`. They just need the default import to still work there.

Comment: That's not a "default export" (which is an ES6 module term), that's just a module object (or "`module.exports` object" if you want to be specific).

Comment: Why don't you just write `cool_func` as a method of `common`, in exactly the same place and syntax as the existing `dostuff`?

Comment: I've tried various synatx, combing through stackoverflow, asking the AI, and reading https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#moduleexports @PrerakSola.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/silly-meninsky-mm75zf?file=/common.js:11,25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Assign the named export as a property

You could assign the new export as a property on your current export.

For example:

```
// common.js

const common = {
  doStuff: () => {
    /* ... */
  }
};

const cool_func = () => {
  /* ... */
};

common.cool_func = cool_func;

module.exports = common;
```

Comment: Approach #1 (`module.exports.default`) simply doesn't work - you can try running your code to verify. Approach #2 (assigning as property), however, meets my requirements, and I'd be happy to accept your answer if you edited out the false part.

Answer (score -3):

To export additional objects from your common.js file without modifying some_other_file_1.js, you can create a new object that combines both common and cool_func and export that new object. Here's how you can do it:

common.js (modified):

```
const common = {

dostuff: () => {
    // code I've omitted
  },
};

const cool_func = () => {
  // code I've omitted
};

// Create a new object that combines common and cool_func
const combinedExports = {
  common,
  cool_func,
};

module.exports = combinedExports;
```

Now, some_other_file_1.js can still use the common object as it did before, and other files can access cool_func as follows:

some_other_file_1.js (unchanged):

```
const common = require('common');

const foo = () => {
  common.dostuff();
};
```

Another_file.js (or any other file that wants to use cool_func):

```
const common = require('common');

common.cool_func(); // You can now use cool_func
```

By creating the combinedExports object in common.js, you can export both the original common object and the new cool_func function without modifying the importing code in some_other_file_1.js.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't work, because you overwrite `module.exports` with a new object

Comment: The first line is pointless as the object will be overwritten immediately in the second line

Comment: This kind of syntax was the first thing I've tried, and sadly it didn't work. I receive an error that looks like "common.dostuff is not a function" when running `some_other_file_1.js`

Comment: `dostuff` is now accessible through `common.common.dostuff` in `some_other_file_1.js`, so it will break.

Comment: Lev G's original answer (which was completely different and edited) did not work for the reason I specified. The current answer still doesn't solve my issue, since it requires me to change `some_other_file_1.js` to use the syntax `common.common.dostuff()`, which means the current code snippet doesn't work.